# Navigate throughout balkan org chart

Tags: javascript, orgchart

I am using balkan org chart and want to navigation throughout the diagram when click and hold the mouse on the nodes also in mobile device when i touch and hold the on nodes can't navigate . is this option available ?
as default for navigation only click and hold outside of a node it's possible to navigate.
Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the option:
nodeMouseClick: OrgChart.action.pan
https://balkan.app/OrgChartJS/API/interfaces/OrgChart.options#nodeMouseClick